# Allows only numbers from -5 to 75 AND one decimal that is a 5

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I would like some help with a regEx pattern that only allows the numbers -5 to 75 and one decimal that ends in 5 for an input type="text". e.g:

```
-5 
-4.5
12
0.5
66.5 
75
```

I have this regExp `^-?(?:[0-6]?[0-9](?:\\.5)?|7[0-5](?:\\.5)?|75(?:\\.0)?)$`. However, it accepts -5.5 or -12. How can I fix this?

Comment: from -5.00 to 75.00 or is -5.99999 to 75.9999 also acceptable?

Comment: @Thefourthbird "*and one decimal that ends in 5*" - I would guess this means the input can end in `.5` or not - so you question would be is 75.5 allowed

Comment: I think the question needs to be clarified, but it seems that the only options are integers, or floats of `.5`? I'm a little curious as the use-case here, because rather than regular expressions to check the number it would seem easier to find the number and then test to see if it's within the acceptable range.

Comment: @freedomn-m Ah yes, I did not read it thoroughly

Comment: What is the _context_ in which you need to perform this check; _can_ you use _only_ regex? Because regex aren't really a _good_ tool to perform these kind of "range checks" to begin with ... you'd be using a screwdriver to hammer in a nail here.

Comment: @Thefourthbird your question was still valid/relevant though

Answer (score 4):

You may use this regex to check numbers between `-5` to `75`, optionally allowing `.5`:

```bash
^(?:-5|75|(?:-[1-4]|\d|[1-6]\d|7[0-4])(?:\.5)?)$
```

##### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/d156oJ/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`
- `(?:`: Start the outer non-capture group

  - `-5`: Match `-5`
  - `|`: OR
  - `75`:
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?:`: Start the inner non-capture group

    - `-[1-4]`: Match `-1` to `-4`
    - `|`: OR
    - `\d`: Match any single digit i.e. `0` to `9`
    - `|`: OR
    - `[1-6]\d`: Match `10` to `69`
    - `|`: OR
    - `7[0-4]`: match `70` to `74`
  - `)`: End the inner non-capture group
  - `(?:\.5)?`: Optionally match `.5`
- `)`: End the outer non-capture group
- `$`: End

Comment: @thegreenedition: Did this work out?